# How to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss.millisecond format c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, time

I need to convert seconds in to hh:mm:ss.milliseconds and I need that this format must be respected. I mean that hours, minutes and seconds must have 2 digits and milliseconds 3 digits.
For example, if seconds = 3907.1 I would to obtain 01:05:07.100

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    double sec_tot = 3907.1;
    double hour = sec_tot/3600; // seconds in hours
    double hour_int;
    double hour_fra = modf(hour, &hour_int );//split integer and decimal part of hours
    double minutes = hour_fra*60; // dacimal hours in minutes
    double minutes_int;
    double minutes_fra = modf(minutes, &minutes_int); // split integer and decimal part of minutes
    double seconds = minutes_fra*60; // decimal minutes in seconds
    stringstream ss;
    ss << ("%02lf", hour_int) << ":" << ("%02lf", minutes_int) << ":" << ("%02lf", seconds);
    string time_obs_def = ss.str();
    cout << time_obs_def << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

but the output is  1:5:7.1
Thank you.

Comment: `ss << ("%02lf", hour_int)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: You may also have a look to the documentation of [std::chrono::duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration). It could be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nowadays you should probably use the chrono duration [std::chrono::milliseconds](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) for such a task, but if you'd like make our own type to support formatting, something like this should do it:

```
#include <iomanip>   // std::setw & std::setfill
#include <iostream>

// your own type
struct seconds_t {
    double value;
};

// ostream operator for your type:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const seconds_t& v) {
    // convert to milliseconds
    int ms = static_cast<int>(v.value * 1000.);

    int h = ms / (1000 * 60 * 60);
    ms -= h * (1000 * 60 * 60);

    int m = ms / (1000 * 60);
    ms -= m * (1000 * 60);

    int s = ms / 1000;
    ms -= s * 1000;

    return os << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << h << ':' << std::setw(2) << m
              << ':' << std::setw(2) << s << '.' << std::setw(3) << ms;
}

int main() {
    seconds_t m{3907.1};
    std::cout << m << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Coming in C++20:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int
main()
{
    double sec_tot = 3907.1;
    cout << format("{:%T}\n", round<milliseconds>(duration<double>{sec_tot}));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` style format specifiers do not work. You will need to use the stream manipulators to set the [width](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [fill character](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill).

```
ss << std:setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hour_int;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also add a leading zero to enforce hh:mm:ss format.
If hh is 00, returns only mm:ss.
ms are left out from this example, but easy to add.

```
#include <iostream>

std::string convertSecondsToHHMMSS (int value) {
  std::string result;
  // compute h, m, s
  std::string h = std::to_string(value / 3600);
  std::string m = std::to_string((value % 3600) / 60);
  std::string s = std::to_string(value % 60);
  // add leading zero if needed
  std::string hh = std::string(2 - h.length(), '0') + h;
  std::string mm = std::string(2 - m.length(), '0') + m;
  std::string ss = std::string(2 - s.length(), '0') + s;
  // return mm:ss if hh is 00
  if (hh.compare("00") != 0) {
    result = hh + ':' + mm + ":" + ss;
  }
  else {
    result =  mm + ":" + ss;
  }
  return result;
}

int main() {
  std::cout << convertSecondsToHHMMSS(3601) << "\n";
  std::cout << convertSecondsToHHMMSS(1111) << "\n";
  std::cout << convertSecondsToHHMMSS(60) << "\n";
  std::cout << convertSecondsToHHMMSS(12) << "\n";
  std::cout << convertSecondsToHHMMSS(0) << "\n";
}
```